# Angularjs: get parent element width

Tags: angularjs

html"

```
<div id="parent">
      <input type=button ng-click="getWidth()">
</div>
```

js:

```
 function Ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.getWidth = function(){
           // How to get div[id=parent] width here?
        } 

    }
```

So my question is how to get parent div in getWidth method?

Comment: You could access the dom by injecting `$document` or `$element` into your controller but better practice would be to put DOM stuff into directives. We could give a better answer if you provide more information would you want to do with parent's width.

Answer (score 1):

like hansmaad's answer, you better use directive for handling DOM stuffs.

```
app.directive('getWidth', ['$timeout', '$location', function($timeout, $location) {
  return {
    scope: {
      callbackFn: "&"
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.callbackFn({width: elem[0].clientWidth});
    }
  }
}]);
```

in html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" >
    <div get-width callback-fn="returnWidth(width)" style="height:100%; width: 100%;">
          <p >Hello {{name}}!</p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

working example  [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fs4EggYVenJI15ucB13W?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

use `$event.target` to get the element click and then use jquery to find width

```js
function SimpleController($scope) {
  $scope.width = 0;
  $scope.getWidth = function($event) {
    // How to get div[id=parent] width here?
    $scope.width = $($event.target).parent().outerWidth();

  }
}
```

```css
#parent{
  background-color : red;
  width : 200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="" ng-controller="SimpleController">


  <div id="parent">
    parent width : {{width}}
    <button type=button ng-click="getWidth($event)"> find width </button>
  </div>

</div>
```